# Declaration needed

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a c type single entry Schengen visa issued from Spain. And this is my first time Schengen visa. I want to go to Rome first for 3 days and then to Spain for 4 days and then back to my country from Spain. Is that authorized or do I have to enter through Spain first?

Comment: The airline will deny you boarding if they believe you will not be admitted to the destination country. There's probably something in the "terms and conditions" of your ticket which says they reserve the right to do so.

Comment: I've rolled the edits back to the original question, which is a reasonable duplicate of the linked question. Your edits completely changed the nature of the question so rather than edit a different question into this one, ask a new question.

Comment: # Roddy of the Frozen Peas ... I've shown them my internal flight tickets and the hotel's non-refundable confirmation and the international return tickets from Barcelona